# Error in reading .gz file in python using gzip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, gzip, python-3.9

I am using code to read file from AWS s3 bucket using boto3, throwing error "Not a gzipped file (b'\xef\xbb')"
even if filename is ends with .gz and the content type is also application/x-gzip, it throwing erorr to uncompress the input file
how can i handle this.

```
import gzip

job.file_bucket = 'upload-bucket'
job.file_path = 'filepath/filename.gz'
s3client = AwsS3Service.get_client(True)
file_object = s3client.Object(job.file_bucket, job.file_path)

job.file_object = file_object.get()['Body']
content_type = file_object.get()["ContentType"]
job.cFilePath = f"{job.file_bucket}/{job.file_path}"

if content_type == 'application/x-gzip' or (content_type == 'binary/octet-stream' and     job.cFilePath.endswith('.gz')):
    with gzip.open(job.file_object, 'rb') as file:
        xml_data = file.read()
```

Comment: I suspect `file_object.get()['Body']` is not getting what you want. Of course there is the question, are you sure the file is named correctly and is in fact a gzip file. Which library are you using to access the AwsS3Service? Instead of using gzip, you could try just writing the file to disk, and opening it with something else?

Comment: Hi @matt,
Thanks for replying.
I am using boto3 to get file from s3 bucket and using gzip to uncompressend gz file.
File name is ends with .gz and if i  extract content of file it is also showing application/x-gzip

Comment: I would try this simple download example, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html and check to make sure the file is OK and a gzip file after you've saved it.

Comment: Hi @matt ,
my program is doing some other operations by reading that file and storing in object (I am reading other files also like .zip, .bz2, .zml).
Can you please provide me solution to avoid that error which i am facing with gz file.

Comment: gzip is a pretty simple interface. You seem to be providing it something that isn't a .gz file. I would try saving it and checking if it works. Then if that works, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: You would get better (or any) answers if you provided the error trace. My guess, however, is that  `job.file_object` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) takes a filename, not file object.  If you want to decompress a file object, use the [GzipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) class.